# How do I work around Unity not generating ICONIFY events when a window is minimized?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, ubuntu-unity

I'm trying to work around this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/998073

> According to the gtk documentation, and application should receive a window-state-event notification when the main window is minimized. The window's state should also indicate that it is now iconified. Unity does not deliver this notification to the application or change the window's state to indicate that it has happened.

As the bug report describes, Unity is not generating `GDK_WINDOW_STATE_ICONIFIED` when a window is minimized via the GUI.

Basically, I've got a master window and a slave window (which has no title bar).  I need the slave window to minimize and unminimize itself along with the master.  In other window managers, the code I have works fine because as it's written it depends on the iconify signal, which other window managers are so kind as to deliver to my application when the user attempts to minimize them.

I've searched all over the interwebs and have not found any workarounds.  Does anyone have relevant hints, tips, experience, or workarounds?